# ansible.posix.profile_tasks callback – adds time information to tasks

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I would like to use the `ansible.posix.profile_tasks` callback plugins, which adds time information to tasks and overall execution time. I added already to my `ansible.cfg` the:

```ini
[defaults]
callback_whitelist = ansible.posix.profile_task
```

but I ran into this error when I execute the playbook:

```
[ansible@control setup]$ ansible-playbook -i inventory  hp.yml
[WARNING]: Skipping callback plugin 'ansible.posix.profile_tasks', unable to load
```

I already installed the `ansible.posix`. I saw in the documentation:

> To use it in a playbook, specify: ansible.posix.profile_tasks.`

I tried everything but the issue persists. Any idea please.

Answer (score 3):

In Ansible v2.9, I am only able to reproduce the error if using the full name [`ansible.posix.profile_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/profile_tasks_callback.html#examples) within the config file [`ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html).

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml
[WARNING]: Skipping callback plugin 'ansible.posix.profile_tasks', unable to load
...
```

With just `profile_tasks` in example in

```ini
[defaults]
...
callback_whitelist      = timer, profile_tasks
stdout_callback         = yaml
...
```

the profiling was working properly.

So it might be related to your installed versions and used configurations.

**Further Documenation**

- [Ansible v2.9 - `profile_tasks` – adds time information to tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.html)
- [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html)
- [Index of all Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, it seems very interesting and i will try to check another controller node to simulate the and to add the same lines in my ansible.cfg file. I will keep you updated